# highlight two dates with different colours in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

In bootstrap date-picker i want to highlight two dates. I am able to highlight two dates but unable to differentiate the two date by color or some class it apply same blue color for both dates. Can any one help?

```
var DD = "29";
var MM = "04";
var YY = "2014";
var CaseDD = "25";
var CaseMM = "04";
var CaseYY = "2014";

 $('#calendar').datepicker({
 format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
 multidate: true,
 multidateSeparator: "/",
 autoclose: true,
 showOtherMonths: true,
 dayNamesMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
 beforeShowDay: highlightDays()
 });
  $('#calendar').datepicker('setDate', new Date(YY, MM, DD), new Date(CaseYY, CaseMM,           CaseDD));
```